# Join two tables and retrieve relevant data and calculate the result

Tags: sql

We have two tables table1 and table2
Table 1
[image: Table 1]
Table 2

[image]

**We need the resultant table as :**

[image]

**All this should be done in a single SQL query**
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to use some type of join (INNER JOIN, LEFT JOIN etc.). They are used to join multiple tables on some parameter (in your case it will probably be on id_pro). Google these joins, and you will be able to solve this problem, they are pretty simple to use. Simplest way is to use `SELECT * FROM table_1 INNER JOIN table_2 ON table_1.id_pro = table_2.id_pro`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can make it without the second query, I tested it and returned your expected values.

```
select     table_2.id_pro, 
           product_name, 
           SUM(1) as Quantity, 
           priceprod, 
           SUM(1) * priceprod as 'quantity * priceprod'
from       Table_2
inner join Table_1 t1 on table_2.id_pro = t1.id_pro
group by   table_2.id_pro, product_name, priceprod
```

And my SqlFiddle test http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/08c2ef/1

Comment: we have updated the question with tables pls check and help me

Comment: you just have to replace "id_pro" with "product", or is any other change I'm missing?

Comment: how did you count the Quantity of each item

Comment: using the sum along with the group by gives you the number. You can use count(1), replace sum(1) with count(1) and will render the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should be what you need, or fairly close anyway! You need to group up your results from your first table to get your quantity value and then join those results to your second table to be able to create your desired output.

```
SELECT     t1.id_pro,
           t2.product_name,
           s.Quantity,
           t2.priceperprod,
           s.Quantity * t2.priceperprod
FROM       table_2 t2
INNER JOIN (
           SELECT COUNT(*) AS Quantity,
                  t.id_pro
           FROM   table_1 t
           GROUP BY t.id_pro
           ) t1 ON t2.id_pro = t1.id_pro
```

Answer (score 0):

i believe that this is correct, i just JOIN the two tables AND used group by then count how many records each group, i hope this will help you, thanks.

```
SELECT
  A.id_pro,
  A.product_name,
  (count(*))     AS Quantity,
  A.priceperprod,
  (COUNT(*) * A.priceperprod) AS Total
FROM table_2 A
  LEFT JOIN table_1 B
    ON B.id_pro = A.id_pro
GROUP BY A.id_pro
```

Answer (score 0):

Guess this should be helpful to you.

```
SELECT A.PRODUCT_CODE, A.PRODUCT_NAME, B.QUANTITY,
 A.PRICE PRICE_PER_PRODUCT,
 (B.QUANTITY * A.PRICE) TOTAL_PRICE FROM
 TABLE2 A,
 (SELECT X.PRODUCT, COUNT(X.PRODUCT) QUANTITY FROM TABLE1 AS X
 GROUP BY X.PRODUCT) as B
 WHERE A.PRODUCT_CODE = B.PRODUCT
 ORDER BY A.PRODUCT_CODE
```

Am doing following :

1. Taking the entire TABLE2 aliased as A
2. Getting the products and its corresponding count using group by and aliasing it as B
3. Selecting corresponding fields from table_Aliases A and B provided A's ProductCode and B's Products are same.